# Spring filters working flow

Tags: spring-security

i am using spring mvc. for login whenever request comes it passes through various Filters to get the flow(as different flow for different types of users). please suggest me a good reference to Spring Filters. or a good example on it. how to configure context.xml,web.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need something other than the spring security docs ?

[This](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) is the page from the official docs related to filters.

Comment: i am working on login. and user request come through various filter and there are different URl. user can be redirected to those url based on some condition.i did't able to understand the flow.  please advice me how to get that flow. as i have to implement a new flow. Thanks Again.

Comment: @user816130 You want to reorder the filters ?

Comment: thanks Simeon for response. Yes i want to reorder it. is there any way to know that in filter chain which filter will be called next. Once again thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Filters need to be configured in both the application context.xml and the web.xml file in your project. Here are examples of each of these files and also a Login filter that I wrote for my application... Hope it helps.

Web.xml

```
<filter> 
    <filter-name>randomFilter</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name> 
        <param-value>true</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
</filter>
```

Filter mappings also need to be specified in this file and the order in which these mappings occur decide which filter is called first.

```
<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>randomFilter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

In the application context.xml,  we mention the filter path, for example:

```
    <bean id="randomFilter" class="folderPath.RandomFilter"/>
```